# jq: pass space-divided string as value

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to create new key-pair in existing JSON file where both key and value are sent as variables.
I have the one-line command:

```bsh
jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" 'getpath(path('$key')) = '$value'' "$json"
```

where:
$key - key
$value - value
$json - file containing JSON data

For example, my value is `Linux CentOS`, so when I'm running the command, I'll get

```bsh
+ jq --arg key .operating_system.NAME --arg value 'CentOS Linux' 'getpath(path(.operating_system.NAME)) = CentOS' Linux ./servername_1648782569.json
jq: error: CentOS/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
getpath(path(.operating_system.NAME)) = CentOS
jq: 1 compile error
```

---

**UPD**:
My JSON data at moment when script face it:

```json
{
  "operating_system": {}
}
```

The value I'm trying to paste is
`NAME="CentOS Linux"`
from
`/etc/os-release`

the function that assigning values:

```bsh
function assign_value ()                                                                          
{                                                                                                 
  if [ -z "$1" ]                                                                                  
  then                                                                                            
    echo __msg_error "Key is not passed as argument."                                             
    exit 1                                                                                        
  elif [ -z "$2" ]                                                                                
  then                                                                                            
    echo __msg_error "Value is not passed as argument."                                           
    exit 1                                                                                        
  elif [ -z "$3" ]                                                                                
  then                                                                                            
    echo __msg_error "JSON file path is not passed as argument."                                  
    exit 1                                                                                        
  fi                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
  key="$1"                                                                                        
  value="$2"                                                                                      
  json="$3"                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
  tmp=$(mktemp)                                                                                   
  jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" "getpath(path("$key")) = "$value"" "$json" > "$tmp"
  mv -- "$tmp" "$json"                                                                            
}
```

the place wherefrom args passed to function above

```bsh
...
if test -e /etc/os-release                                              
then                                                                    
        os_release_path='/etc/os-release'                               
else                                                                    
        os_release_path='/usr/lib/os-release'                           
fi                                                                      
. "${os_release_path}"                                                  
                                                                        
MAJOR_VERSION_ID=$(echo $VERSION_ID | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')          
                                                                        
initialize_new_area "$JSON_AREA" "$JSON"                                
                                                                        
#assign_value "${JSON_AREA}.NAME" "$NAME" "$JSON"                       
assign_value "${JSON_AREA}.ID" "$ID" "$JSON"                            
assign_value "${JSON_AREA}.ID_LIKE" "$ID_LIKE" "$JSON"                  
assign_value "${JSON_AREA}.MAJOR_VERSION_ID" "$MAJOR_VERSION_ID" "$JSON"
...
```

Comment: Your quoting is all mixed up and I can't tell what exactly you're intending to do, but note that *both* variables are being expanded *by the shell* before jq starts and neither `--arg` gets used. I don't think that's what you wanted, except that maybe you did for key? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Looks like in the first codeblock you have `'getpath(path('$key')) = '$value''` ... Not sure if this is an unintended typo or if you are accidentally using the wrong syntax, but bash wouldn't know to parse this as one big string literal, but rather as several string literals: `'getpath(path('`, `$key`, `')) = '`, `$value`, and `''`. Even if you limited to only 1 opening and 1 closing apostrophe, variables like `$key` are only expanded outside quotes or inside **double** quotes. Probably, you want this instead:  `"getpath(path('$key')) = '$value'"`. I think the 2nd codeblock has similar issues.

Comment: ^ In that case, since the string literal is enclosed within double-quotes, the variables `$key` and `$value` will be expanded to their respective values. The single-quotes within the string are considered as character literals by bash and this won't be considered for the expansion. In other words, bash would fill in `"getpath(path('$key')) = '$value'"` to be `"getpath(path('.operating_system.NAME')) = 'CentOS Linux'"` which is what `jq` would see. Currently, it looks like `jq` is seeing *multiple* arguments bc the single-quotes are not structured to close the string correctly.

Comment: ^ it's not clear if this is what is preventing your script from working or if it's just an obstacle that we need to clear up first before we can get to the heart of things. I would also suggest editing to include a stripped down sample of the json structure (makes it easier for us to test our answers and confirm before submitting)

Comment: @MichaelHomer, @zpangwin
I updated my first message, thanks to your assumptions.
That's what I get if try to hardcode value. It needs `""`
```json
jq 'getpath(path(.operating_system.ID)) = "Linux CentOS"' servername_1648787273.json
{
  "operating_system": {
    "ID": "Linux CentOS"
  }
}
```

Have no idea how to reproduce this with variable.

If you know how to improve whole code with the first discussed purpose - change value by key:value passed as variable, I would be glad.

P.S. How to add breaklines in comment sections here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating `jq` variables with `--arg`, but you never use these in your `jq` expression.  Instead, you inject the shell variables into the expression (since you use double quotes).  This is part of your issue.

You also can't pass data into `jq` as anything other than a string or a valid JSON document, so giving an *expression* (a path like `.operating_system.NAME`) is impossible.  Instead, pass a string and parse it into a path statement.

Use the `jq` variables in a single-quoted `jq` expression, and parse the given "key" value into something that can be used as a path expression in `jq` by splitting it on dots:

```bsh
jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '
    setpath($key | split("."); $value)' "$json" > "$tmp"
```

Note that the single quotes above will stop the shell from expanding `$key` and `$value` as shell variables.  Instead, these are treated as `jq` internal variables with the values that you've assigned to them using `--arg` (properly encoded by `jq`).

Testing:

```bsh
$ cat file
{
  "operating_system": {}
}
```

```bsh
$ key="operating_system.release.date"
$ value="2022-04-01"
```

```bsh
$ jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" 'setpath($key|split(".");$value)' file
{
  "operating_system": {
    "release": {
      "date": "2022-04-01"
    }
  }
}
```

To support setting array elements in this particular fashion, you need to convert the path elements into numbers, but revert to using them as strings if that conversion fails:

```bsh
jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '
    setpath($key | split(".") |
        map(try tonumber catch null // .); $value)' file
```

Testing:

```bsh
$ key="operating_system.dates.0"
$ value="2022-04-02"
```

```bsh
$ jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" 'setpath($key|split(".")|map(try tonumber catch null // .); $value)' file
{
  "operating_system": {
    "dates": [
      "2022-04-02"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works almost as I want. But the next issue is how to set the array element by that way? Split function return number as string

Comment: @АлексейПашнин See update.